# Qt Android Error: arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-fstack-protector-strong'

Tags: android, qt, windows-10

I have an error while building android application with newly installed Qt 5.8.0 for Android in Windows 10
This is my compile output:

```
11:06:25: Running steps for project untitled5...
11:06:26: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\5.8\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\mir.moezi\Documents\untitled5\untitled5.pro -spec android-g++ "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
11:06:28: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\5.8\android_armv7\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
11:06:29: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" qmake_all
mingw32-make: Nothing to be done for 'qmake_all'.
11:06:31: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited normally.
11:06:31: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\5.8\android_armv7\bin\uic.exe ..\untitled5\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
C:\Qt\Android\android-ndk-r10/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -fstack-protector-strong -DANDROID -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -fno-builtin-memmove --sysroot=C:\Qt\Android\android-ndk-r10/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/ -g -g -marm -O0 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\untitled5 -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\5.8\android_armv7\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\5.8\android_armv7\include\QtWidgets -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\5.8\android_armv7\include\QtGui -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\5.8\android_armv7\include\QtCore -I. -I. -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Android\android-ndk-r10\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Android\android-ndk-r10\sources\cxx-stl\gnu-libstdc++\4.8\libs\armeabi-v7a\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Android\android-ndk-r10\platforms\android-16\arch-arm\usr\include -I..\..\..\..\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\5.8\android_armv7\mkspecs\android-g++ -o main.obj ..\untitled5\main.cpp
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-fstack-protector-strong'
Makefile:1291: recipe for target 'main.obj' failed
mingw32-make: *** [main.obj] Error 1
11:06:33: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0_Android\Tools\mingw530_32\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled5 (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.8.0))
When executing step "Make"
11:06:33: Elapsed time: 00:08.
```

Please help me to solve this error!
Here is my packages installed :

```
qt-opensource-windows-x86-android-5.8.0 
JDK.7.Update.80.x64
apache-ant-1.10.1-bin 
Android-NDK32-r10-windows-x86_64
Android.SDK.Release.v24.4.1.Windowsinstaller_r24.4.1-windows
```

what is '-fstack-protector-strong' ?
I think this prevents Qt Creator from continuing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was because of my android NDK, it was a little old.
I removed `Android-NDK32-r10-windows-x86_64` and installed `Android-NDK32-r14-windows-x86_64` and now it works fine.